# How do i do the "IN" and "DISTINCT of SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
SELECT DISTINCT MarketTemplateId AS MarketTemplateID
FROM Market
WHERE Market.FixtureId = ? And
    Market.MarketTemplateId In 
    ('MW3W', '1HTG', 'FTCS', 'HTFT', 'MTG2W', 'MW3W1H','FTCSALT')
```

how would i produce this in LINQ because i tried the below code and it doesn't work

```
var result6 = entityTrading.Markets
            .Where(p => p.FixtureId == InternalFixtureID_F.ToString())
            .FirstOrDefault(p => MarketTemplateIds.Contains(p.MarketTemplateId));
```

Comment: Please improve the format your code. Badly formatted code is lazy and sends a message that your post is not important.

Comment: What DBMS is it? Oracle, Sql Server?...

Comment: You said it doesnt work, but what doesn't work about it? Doesn't compile, doesn't return correct result?

Comment: @GiladGreen sql server

Comment: doesn't compile i think its a wrong implementation

Comment: @AlessandroBonnici "doesn't compile" will give useful error messages - please show them

Comment: @HansKesting I think he was commenting on my answer.  There was a parentheses problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<string> MarketTemplateIds = new List<string>{ "MW3W", "1HTG", "FTCS", "HTFT", "MTG2W", "MW3W1H","FTCSALT" };

var result6 = entityTrading.Markets
            .Where(p => p.FixtureId == InternalFixtureID_F.ToString()
             and MarketTemplateIds.Contains(p.MarketTemplateId ))
            .Select( u => u.MaketTemplateId).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var id = InternalFixtureID_F.ToString();

var result6 = entityTrading.Markets
              .Where(p => p.FixtureId == id  && MarketTemplateIds.Contains(p.MarketTemplateId))
              .Select(m => m.MarketTemplateId)
              .Distinct();
```